# Nordvpn causes some local services to malfunction from my Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Tags: vpn, sshd, minidlna

I have started to use a PC in my house as a server to learn and expand more my knowledge in the IT field. Currently running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, at the moment being used for samba, minidlna, and local ssh.

I've been using Nordvpn in pretty much all the distros I have ever installed for almost 2 years, but I never had the need of using ssh or minidlna until now.

Basically if I have Nordvpn activated on my server I can still ssh into it using the local IP address however the connection is terribly slow, like **A LOT**.

I wanna say it takes anywhere from 5 to 20 seconds (it varies) to the server to execute a command after input.
If I disconnect the VPN, everything works amazing.

As for minidlna, I could say the case is almost the same but with the difference of minidlna not working if vpn is active. (At least on my xbox, because I can still user samba with or without vpn)

Not sure if there is anything I could do to have both services working with my vpn, I have sshd settings modified since default settings is an open door for hackers.

Thanks in advance, if there is any information I could further provide do let me know.

Comment: So its basically due to my ping?

Comment: VPN should not impair your local network connections like that. Do you use any NordVPN features like Kill Switch that might be messing with firewall rules?

Comment: @Sebastian NordVPN linux client has two options to whitelist ports (such as 22) as well as whitelist local subnets. However, I could never get the whitelist port option to work. The local subnet whitelist works allows local LAN `ssh`.

Comment: Have you tried `nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/16` command? This should allow better ssh within your home network. If this works, I will write a full answer.

Comment: I have a different port set up for sshd, could that be the issue?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1269023/edit) and tell us if using a different port is an issue. We don't have your setup. We can't tell you what should or shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass nordvpn by whitelisting whatever you need.

You can whitelist ports (e.g. default ssh port 22):

```
nordvpn whitelist add port 22
```

You can whitelist whole subnets (e.g. your local network)

```
nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/16
```

To make minidlna work, you can whitelist the UPNP/SSDP broadcast address:

```
nordvpn whitelist add subnet 239.255.255.250/32
```

I don't know how much that impacts your privacy but I do know that it gets rid of the pesky error `minissdp.c:313: error: sendto(udp_notify=9, 192.168.0.1): Operation not permitted`.

This will allow your local devices to discover your minidlna server. To enable actual streaming, you'll also need to either whitelist your local network or the minidlna port (8200 by default).

Comment: I am having a similar issue causing a system freeze when connected to NordVPN and accessing a NFS share. Since this problem first appeared after an upgrade of the NordVPN app, I contacted NordVPN support. I personally view whitelisting as a workaround, not a solution. This issue causes users considerable inconvenience in the form of multiple reboots and looking for a solution, not to mention questions re: privacy. This requires a dev-side fix or an confirmation that it cannot be fixed for some reason. I am in contact with NordVPN support.